# Does ArcGIS Pro have a tool like PostGIS ST_ReducePrecision?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, precision

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Pro to reduce the precision of a geometry in a dataset, similar to https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ReducePrecision.html?

I want to use it on a file geodatabase dataset I have uploaded to AGOL. The idea behind is to see if this decreases the size of the resulting hosted feature layer.

Comment: See https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/migrating-to-high-precision.htm that states "Storing data at a larger resolution slightly improves performance and lowers storage requirements."

Comment: Using Ramer-Douglas-Peucker or one of the other generalization methods via [Simplify Polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/cartography/simplify-polygon.htm) is part of what you want, but you can also define a feature dataset with a coarser resolution, and copy the resulting feature class into that (before moving it back out again), which would be similar to ST_SnapToGrid.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll check it out!